# Assign column names to list of dataframes

Tags: r

I have a list of dataframes, whose columns have names.

If I want to change the names of the dataframes within the list (rather than the names of the parent list), I cannot access them directly via names() or colnames(), rather I must use lapply() to get the names.

However, if I use lapply to return the column names, then they only exist within the lapply call, and I cannot assign new names to the list in the parent environment.

Here's a MWE below:

*1/ Create the object*

```
require(xts)
data(sample_matrix)
x <- as.xts(sample_matrix)
y <- lapply(split(x, "months"), data.frame)
```

*2/ The column names of the dataframes are not directly accessible*

```
names(y)
```

> NULL

```
colnames(y)
```

> NULL

*3/ We can try to use lapply*

```
lapply(y, function(z) names(z) <- c('Op', 'Hi', 'Lo', 'Clo'))
```

> [[1]]
>
> [1] "Op"  "Hi"  "Lo"  "Clo" ...

But it hasn't actually assigned names to the object.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use `setNames`...

```
lapply( y , setNames , nm = c('Op', 'Hi', 'Lo', 'Clo') )
#[[1]]
#                 Op       Hi       Lo      Clo
#2007-01-02 50.03978 50.11778 49.95041 50.11778
#2007-01-03 50.23050 50.42188 50.23050 50.39767
#2007-01-04 50.42096 50.42096 50.26414 50.33236
#       ...      ...      ...      ...      ...
```

Quoting directly from the help page:

> *This is a convenience function that sets the names on an object and returns the object. It is most useful at the end of a function definition where one is creating the object to be returned and would prefer not to store it under a name just so the names can be assigned.*

Comment: Nice, never seen that function before.